# What manufacture made this shower valve?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

[image]

- Will new/differnt style bathroom fixtures work with this valve?
- What style/manufacture valve is this
- Do I have to replace the Valve lining parts or cut copper pipes and replace the entire valve?
- [image: List item]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: do you still have the handle

Comment: You have the wall open already. New valves are not that expensive, Do yourself a favor and replace it with something like a Moen that is easy to get parts and trim for. That old thing can nag you till you scream.

Comment: Ruskes Ive attatched a photo of the handle

Comment: @RMDman Yep thanks for the tip that's what Im going to end up doing I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with @RMDman recommendation. I didn't want to run into any guessing game or problems with this old valve (built in the late 70's). I purchased a new Delta Kit and will be soldering new copper elbows and nuts, keeping the main copper plumbing intact.